# Python root level logs not displayed except for error

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

Logs with level `INFO` are not being displayed when using logging configuration.

Below is my logging config.

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]

keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('../common/logs/file.log','a',1024*1024,3)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(filename)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

I also tried adding the below in the file:

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Still only errors are displayed in the log.

Comment: what happens when you `level=NOTSET` instead of `level=INFO` for root logger in your config file ? BTW, if you can also add the code snippet for your logger, it will be much easier for people to assist you.

Comment: It was set to NOTSET initially and still the issue existed.

Comment: As a workaround, I added one more logger and changed logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) to logger = logging.getLogger(<custom logger's name>). Now, since the file doesn't fall under root, the messages are displayed.